# jquery animate the page background-color on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to just change the background colour of a webpage upon page load. I see no reason why this shouldn't work, "body" is the correct element I wish to manipulate.  I am using http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/animate as a reference.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: "#000000" }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/aqrvA/8/

Add Jquery ui library as well please Rest will work like a rocket! < Your code is fine >

*Jquery UI link:* http://jqueryui.com/

Hope this helps, `:)`

**Script:**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html body").animate({ backgroundColor: "#000000" }, 1000);
});​
```

Comment: @johnsonwi: Make sure to accept the answer that solved your issue.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl thanks you for the awesomeness :) @ johnsonwi Glad I can help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't animate colors using **only** jQuery. You must use jQuery UI, that extends the animations to colors. [Look here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) :)

Answer (score 1):

> "The jQuery UI effects core extends the animate function to be able to
>   animate colors as well. These transitions can animate the background
>   and border colors and accept colors specified in hex, rgb and color
>   names."

You will not be able to use animate function until you load `jquery-ui.js`

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js

This is what you need.